# How to use Mechanize, BeautifulSoup, html2text on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm deploying my app to Heroku which uses mechanize, beautifulsoup4 and html2text but there are some errors regarding to the missing dependencies on heroku.

I can only manage to install BeautifulSoup by adding this line to the requirements.txt:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.1.3
```

However, I couldn't find away to install mechanize and html2text by adding to requirements.txt. I tried couple thing like: mechanize=xxx html2text=xxx (xxx = different versions) but none of them work so far.

How do I add those 2 dependencies to my requirements.txt in order to make it work on Heroku?

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you see any errors in the heroku output? If so, what?

Comment: it pops out "500 Internal Server Error" page, the app runs fine on local pc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just run pip freeze > requirements.txt and it will replace the old file by the new one with all dependencies. No need to manually add it.